# TeeChart CalcClickedPart Bug after Marks.Item[nPoint].Visible :=false

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart

Delphi 10.1 Pro, VCL with embedded Teechart controls.
CalcClickedPart shows cpSeriesMarks after a Marks set to be hidden at the place it was previously shown.

I may not deleting Marks correctly, only hiding it, or there is a bug in CalcClickedPart. Please advice.

I added a tLabel on the top-left which show the CalcClickedPart Part result.
Also a button to toggle the Marks visibility.

The series & Marks creation:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;
  with Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries) as TLineSeries do
    begin
      for i := 0 to 9 do
        begin
          AddXY(i, 10);
          Marks.Item[i].Visible := false; // Hide all Marks
        end;

      Marks.Show; // A global Marks enabled.
      Marks.Item[5].Visible := true;
    end;
end;
```

CalcClickedPart test:

```
procedure TForm2.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
Var
  ClickedPart: tChartClickedPart;
  sCursorText: string;
begin
  sCursorText := '';

  Chart1.CalcClickedPart(Point(X, Y), ClickedPart); // Return information about the TeeChart component below the Mouse pointer at an X,Y location.
  Case ClickedPart.Part of
    cpNone          : sCursorText := 'cpNone';
    cpLegend        : sCursorText := 'cpLegend';
    cpAxis          : sCursorText := 'cpAxis';
    cpSeries        : sCursorText := 'cpSeries';
    cpTitle         : sCursorText := 'cpTitle';
    cpFoot          : sCursorText := 'cpFoot';
    cpChartRect     : sCursorText := 'cpChartRect';
    cpSeriesMarks   : sCursorText := 'cpSeriesMarks';
    cpSeriesPointer : sCursorText := 'cpSeriesPointer ';
    cpSubTitle      : sCursorText := 'cpSubTitle';
    cpSubFoot       : sCursorText := 'cpSubFoot';
    cpAxisTitle     : sCursorText := 'cpAxisTitle';
  end;

  Label1.Caption := sCursorText;
end;
```

The Marks visibility toggling:

```
procedure TForm2.btnMarksToggleClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with (Chart1[0] as tLineSeries).Marks.Item[5] do
    Visible := not Visible;
end;
```

[Marks is visible. A correct cpSeriesMarks (cursor in Red arrow):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzJyI.png)

Press the button to hide the Marks. Will get the following wrong CalcClickedPart.
[Marks is NOT visible. An incorrect cpSeriesMarks (cursor in Red arrow):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJbzb.png)

Do you have any idea for work around?

p.s I previously found a bug with CalcClickedPart when CalcVisiblePoints := false.
This is another issue, not related to CalcVisiblePoints at all.

Thanks
Reron

Comment: I don't see that as a bug at all. Setting Visible := false doesn't remove the mark, it just doesn't draw it. The mark is still in its location.

Comment: Tom, it is a point of view. Do you know how to delete/remove a single Mark completely? or hide it from CalcClickedPart when it is not visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the problem here so I've added it to the public tracker ([#2092](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=2092)).

Note the problem is at `TSeriesMarks.Clicked` function.
I've already fixed it for the next versions.

As a workaround, you could set `Positions.Item[5]:=nil`:

```
procedure TForm2.btnMarksToggleClick(Sender: TObject);
const aMarksIndex = 5;
begin
  with (Chart1[0] as tLineSeries).Marks do
  begin
    with Item[aMarksIndex] do
      Visible := not Visible;

    if not Item[aMarksIndex].Visible then
       Positions.Items[aMarksIndex]:=nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Yeray. Can I assume there is a class or an object created for each Mark? It is created on the 1st time a Marks is shown. If the assumption is correct, can it be free/disposed somehow by code? Something like "Marks.Items[aMarksIndex].CleanupInstance;" which doesn't help. I also tried to set "Marks.Items[aMarksIndex]" AutoSize:=false, Width=Height=0 and RePaint, It was also was not a solution.

Comment: The `TSeriesMarks.Clicked` function loops the `Marks.Positions` array. So, you could set the `Marks.Positions.Count:=0` to force resetting the positions.

Comment: I think this workaround is better than the one I initially proposed, so I'll move the first thought to the end of the answer

Comment: Yeray, thank you - it is working for me. Based on yours direction, may I offer Marks.Positions.Items[aMarksIndex] := nil. It is dedicated to a single Mark.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I think I tested `Marks.Positions[5]:=nil;` which gives an Access Violation. I'll edit the answer with that code.